# How can I change my value with Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My code give me an infinite loop he never go in if or else, I'm pretty sure that because firebase get only asynchronous function.
I want to check if "random_hexa" exist, and get new random until I get a value who don't exist on my database

```
while (bool_check_while_exist == false)
    {
        ref.child("Salons").child(random_hexa).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
            if (snapshot.exists())
            {
                random_hexa = self.randomAlphaNumericString(5)
            }
            else
            {
                bool_check_while_exist = true
            }
        })
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve? this sounds a typical [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Are just trying to get a random entry from `/Salons`?

Comment: Don't to do this. If you are waiting for a value to change in a node, attach an observer to that node and when it changes, your app will be notified.

Comment: Adolfosrs I try to see if my random value is already use and if yes, i want run randomAlphaNumericString() until I get value who is not on my database

Jay I don't want value change in node I just want to check if a node with the value random_hexa exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running a local while-loop that doesn't handle the asynchronous nature of your Firebase database (and of most of the modern internet). The correct flow would be to:

1. generate a random value
2. start a call to the database to see if that value already exists
3. wait for that call to complete
4. if the value doesn't exist yet, be happy
5. else start again

This can be most easily done with a recursive function:

```
func findUniqueNumber(ref: FIRDatabaseReference, withBlock: (value: Int) -> ()) {
    let random_number = Int(arc4random_uniform(6) + 1)
    ref.child(String(random_number)).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
        if (snapshot.exists())
        {
            print("Rejected \(random_number)")
            self.findUniqueNumber(ref, withBlock: withBlock)
        }
        else
        {
            withBlock(value: random_number)
        }
    })
}
```

Which you then call as:

```
findUniqueNumber(ref, withBlock: { value in
    print(value)
})
```